# Android ListView clickable with AlertDialog

Tags: c#, android, listview, xamarin

I'm attempting to make an store page **clickable**. I'm using a custom listview that shows a **AlertDialog** about the item clicked.

My goal is, when I click on the button, open an alert dialog that allows the purchase.

When I scroll down all the list, many alertDialog are **shown**, instead of only **one**!

My custom adapter extends from **BaseAdapter**, and my getView() method looks like this:

```
public override View GetView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{
    var row = convertView;
    ViewHolder holder = null;

    if(row == null)
    {
        var inflater = context.GetSystemService(Context.LayoutInflaterService) as LayoutInflater;
        row = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.SingleRowStorePage, parent, false);

        holder = new ViewHolder(row);
        row.Tag = holder;

    } else
    {
        holder = (ViewHolder)row.Tag;
    }           

    //SET DATA
    holder.Qtd.Text = "Qtd:" + quantities[position];
    holder.Stock.Text = "Stock: " + shops[position].Stock.ToString();
    holder.Name.Text = shops[position].Name;
    holder.Creditos.Text = shops[position].Price.ToString() + " créditos ";

    //CLICK
    holder.Image.Click += delegate
    {
        Android.Support.V4.App.FragmentTransaction trans = manager.BeginTransaction();
        DialogShop dialog = new DialogShop(shops[position]);
        dialog.Show(trans, "image");
    };

    //confirm shop?
    holder.Comprar.Click += delegate
    {
        AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
        alert.SetTitle("Confirmar compra? item " + shops[position].Name + " com valor: " + quantities[position]);
        alert.SetMessage("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.");
        alert.SetPositiveButton("Ok", (senderAlert, args) =>
        {
            //Toast.MakeText(context, "Ok!", ToastLength.Short).Show();
        });

        alert.SetNegativeButton("Cancelar", (senderAlert, args) =>
        {
            //Toast.MakeText(context, "Cancelar!", ToastLength.Short).Show();
        });

        Dialog dialog = alert.Create();
        dialog.Show();
        dialog.Dismiss();
    };

    return row;
}
```

My ViewHolder:

```
private class ViewHolder : Java.Lang.Object
{
    public ImageView Image { get; set; }
    public Button Qtd { get; set; }
    public TextView Stock { get; set; }
    public TextView Name { get; set; }
    public TextView Creditos { get; set; }
    public Button Comprar { get; set; }

    public ViewHolder(View view)
    {
        Image = view.FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.singleRowStore);
        Qtd = view.FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.buttonComprar);
        Stock = view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.stockStore);
        Name = view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.nomeStore);
        Creditos = view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.creditosStore);
        Comprar = view.FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.comprarStore);
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: You want to show alert dialog when scroll or when btn is clicked?

Comment: When the button is clicked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are using a delegate to hook up your events and since cells can be recycled, you are appending additional Click Events every time a cell is reused.

In your adapter instead of this:

```
holder.Image.Click += delegate
{
    Android.Support.V4.App.FragmentTransaction trans = manager.BeginTransaction();
    DialogShop dialog = new DialogShop(shops[position]);
    dialog.Show(trans, "image");
};
```

Do this instead for all your handlers:

```
holder.Image.Click -= ImageClicked;
holder.Image.Click += ImageClicked;

private void ImageClicked (object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Android.Support.V4.App.FragmentTransaction trans = manager.BeginTransaction();
    DialogShop dialog = new DialogShop(shops[position]);
    dialog.Show(trans, "image");
}
```

You should avoid delegates or anonymous lambdas when possible since you can't get back a reference to the original method and unhook it. (Without keeping a reference to the lamdba with more code).

```
private class ViewHolder : Java.Lang.Object
        {
            //public EventHandler<>
            public ImageView Image { get; set; }
            public Button Qtd { get; set; }
            public TextView Stock { get; set; }
            public TextView Name { get; set; }
            public TextView Creditos { get; set; }
            public Button Comprar { get; set; }

            //New Event Handler
            public EventHandler<ImageClickedEventArgs> ImageClicked;

            public ViewHolder(View view)
            {
                Image = view.FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.singleRowStore);
                Qtd = view.FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.buttonComprar);
                Stock = view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.stockStore);
                Name = view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.nomeStore);
                Creditos = view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.creditosStore);
                Comprar = view.FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.comprarStore);

                Image.Click += Image_Click;
            }

            void Image_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                ImageClicked?.Invoke(sender, new ImageClickedEventArgs(this));
            }

            public class ImageClickedEventArgs : EventArgs
            {
                public ViewHolder ViewHolder { get; private set; }

                public ImageClickedEventArgs(ViewHolder viewHolder) : base()
                {
                    ViewHolder = viewHolder;
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But how can I access the position inside the method ImageClicked?

Comment: This is a different problem than the one in your original post. There are multiple patterns to handle this. One way would be to create a custom EventArgs with an argument that you need. You would then subscribe to it instead of the ImageClick. let me know If you need more help and I can give you all the details.

Comment: Sorry, but doesn't work.
The ImageClicked method is called many times, like the previous approach.

Comment: Are you making sure to unhook ImageClicked before hooking it up ? ImageClicked -= YourImageClickedHandler; ImageClicked += YourImageClickedHandler;